# How do i get taxonomy categories in order to their posts date in wordpress from latest to oldest

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have Video categories in my website homepage. Have a taxonomy called **video-category** and custom post type called **video-list**.

I need to display the taxonomy categories in order to its posts **date** from **latest to oldest**. So that means if i publish one video post today that current post category must be on top as its post have latest date and the rest should go from latest to oldest.

I don't know from where i need to start. Started with getting the latest post and don't know what's the next.

What i currently have is displaying them by most viewed with the below code

```
<ul class="catLists">
                          <?php
                        $video_args = array(
                            'hide_empty' => true,
                            'fields' => 'all',
                            'hierarchical' => true,
                            'child_of' => 0,
                            'get' => '',
                            'name__like' => '',
                            'pad_counts' => false,
                            'taxonomy' => 'video-category',
                            'cache_domain' => 'core'
                        );
                        $v_terms = get_terms('video-category', $video_args);
                        $coount = 1;
                        global $wpdb;
                        foreach($v_terms as $key => $term) {
                            $count_views = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
                                SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) AS view_count FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
                                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
                                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
                                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
                                WHERE pm.meta_key = 'post_views_count'
                                AND tt.taxonomy = 'video-category'
                                AND tt.term_id = %d
                            ", $term->term_id));

                            // Add to the category object the result
                            $v_terms[$key]->count_views = (!empty($count_views)) ? $count_views[0]->view_count : 0;


                        } 
                        function cmp($a, $b) {
                            if ($a->count_views == $b->count_views) {
                                return 0;
                            }
                            return ($a->count_views > $b->count_views) ? -1 : 1;
                        }
                        usort($v_terms, "cmp");
                        foreach ($v_terms as $v_term) {
                            $term_link = get_term_link($v_term, 'video-category');
                            if($coount < 7){ 
                            ?>
                    <li class="video_<?php echo $v_term->term_id; ?>_term" id="<?php echo $coount++ ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $term_link ;?>" id="<?php echo $v_term->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $v_term->name; ?></a>
                        <span class="active_tab_border"></span>
                    </li>
                        <?php  }else{?>
                 <?php if($coount == '7') { ?>
                 </ul>
```

The desired result is to display first the category which post has the latest published date and the rest etc.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Yes but how to get the latest posts with their categories and when new post change the order of categories dynamically?

Comment: Can you provide a basic example showing like "before and after" or expected input and desired result?

Comment: see my question edited @mike510a

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single WP_Query

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'video-list',
    'orderby'    => 'date',
    'category_name' => 'video-category'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: But this will return just all posts in date order, I need them categorized so need to go through all posts in each category, check date and order depending on that.

Comment: use a nested loop --- one loop that does a Query for just category types, and then another query that queries for that particular category and order by date..

Comment: You mean get all posts by date and then sort by category @mike510a?

Comment: Yeah, if thats what your trying to accomplish